# Не передается boolean значение

Tags: java

Класс `ControllerMainMenu`:

```
public class ControllerMainMenu implements Initializable{
    private Boolean[] booleanBuildsMods = new Boolean[3];
    private File fileCheckPresenceBuildMods;
    private String stringLanguage;
    private static Scanner scn;
    private int numberTxtFile=1;
    private StorageVariables storageVariables=new StorageVariables();

    public Boolean getBooleanBuildsMods(int number){
        return booleanBuildsMods[number];
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
            fileCheckPresenceBuildMods=new File("src//sample//StorageVariablesFolder//PresenceBuildMods//"+ numberTxtFile +".txt");

            try{
                scn=new Scanner(new File(String.valueOf(fileCheckPresenceBuildMods)));
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error"); System.out.println("");}

            while(scn.hasNext()){
                booleanBuildsMods[i] =scn.nextBoolean();
            }
            scn.close();

            System.out.println(" *Значение под индексом " + numberTxtFile + " равно " + getBooleanBuildsMods(i)); // Здесь всё выводит правильно
            System.out.println("");

            numberTxtFile++;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс `ControllerCreateNewBuildMods`:

```
public class ControllerCreateNewBuildMods implements Initializable
{
    private Boolean[] booleanBuildsMods;
    private String stringLanguage;
    MyTool myTool = new MyTool();
    private ControllerMainMenu controllerMainMenu = new ControllerMainMenu();
    private StorageVariables storageVariables = new StorageVariables();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)
    {

    }

    public void inquiryQuestionBtnReady() throws IOException
    {
        stringLanguage = storageVariables.getLanguage();
        ResourceBundle lngBndl = ResourceBundle
                .getBundle("sample.Properties.Other", new Locale(stringLanguage));

        if (textfieldCreateNewBuildModsGame.getText().equals("") || textfieldCreateNewBuildModsName.getText().equals(""))
        {
            if (textfieldCreateNewBuildModsGame.getText().equals("") && textfieldCreateNewBuildModsName.getText().equals(""))
            {
                myTool.showMessageDialogMy(true, lngBndl.getString("key_Other_EnterTheNameOfTheAssemblyModsAndTheNameOfTheGame"));
            } else
            {
                if (textfieldCreateNewBuildModsGame.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    myTool.showMessageDialogMy(true, lngBndl.getString("key_Other_EnterTheNameOfTheGame"));
                }
                if (textfieldCreateNewBuildModsName.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    myTool.showMessageDialogMy(true, lngBndl.getString("key_Other_EnterTheNameOfTheAssemblyMods"));
                }
            }
            //Условия выше не какого отношения не имеют к проблеме
        } else
        {
            booleanBuildsMods = new Boolean[3];
            booleanBuildsMods[0] = controllerMainMenu.getBooleanBuildsMods(0);
            booleanBuildsMods[1] = controllerMainMenu.getBooleanBuildsMods(1);
            booleanBuildsMods[2] = controllerMainMenu.getBooleanBuildsMods(2);

            System.out.println(" *Значение под индексом 1 равно " + controllerMainMenu.getBooleanBuildsMods(1));//Здесь выводит null
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Почему передается `null`?

Answer (score 1):

Добавил конструктор ControllerMainMenu и там сделал запись в booleanBuildsMods значений

Comment: Об этом я вам и говорил в своём комментарии

Answer (score 0):

При инициализации ControllerCreateNewBuildMods передавайте ваш ControllerMainMenu, а то суля по вашему коду вы создаёте новый экземпляр класса ControllerMainMenu

Comment: Я не очень вас понял. Вы бы не могли по-подробнее?